# converting Bgr image to YCbCr in EmguCV?

Tags: emgucv

how to convert a Bgr image to YCbCr in EmguCV ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you could use the method img.Convert();

Answer (score 0):

one does not simply Convert a BGR Image into YCbCr...

```
Image<Bgr, byte> BGR;

    Image<Ycc, Byte> YCrCbFrame = BGR.Convert<Ycc, Byte>();
```